# "could not read Username error" when using github CLI in google colab

Tags: github, google-colaboratory, github-cli

I installed the new github CLI in google colab (https://colab.research.google.com/) and authorised.

```
!sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key C99B11DEB97541F0
!sudo apt-add-repository https://cli.github.com/packages
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt install gh

!gh auth login

!gh repo clone <username/repo>
```

I get as a response:

Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
exit status 128

any ideas why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is a credential issue, as shown (in a different context, with GitLAb CI, but with the same idea) with [`cli/cli` issue 1633](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1633#issuecomment-693109142)

Setting a `credential.helper` might help `gh repo clone` to complete properly.